# Get youtube username from channel id

Tags: youtube-data-api

How to get the username of the channel from using the youtube channel id ?

E.g. UCnpaBg-u_kHwzuPyaMcyJ0w is the Channel ID for Sony Max

now how to get username "maxindia" from Youtube v3 Api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the API (for example on [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?try-it)), use `part=snippet` and the channelId you provided, then the `channelTitle` can be found in one of the `items/snippet` objects.

Here is the truncated response:

```
{
  ...
  "items": [
    {
      ...
      "snippet": {
        ...
        "channelTitle": "maxindia",
        ...
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Channel title is not username though

Comment: It works not for all channels. Some Channel IDs return empty result

Comment: which API you are using ?

Comment: You are right you can get `channelTitle `  but not the username. I am using https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Python solution. It tries to find out the channel info from the video ID. Some newer channels only have a channel ID and no username.

```
import requests

API_KEY = "..."

def get_channel_id(vid):
    url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id={vid}&key={api_key}&part=snippet".format(
        vid=vid, api_key=API_KEY
    )
    d = requests.get(url).json()
    return d['items'][0]['snippet']['channelId']

def get_channel_title(cid):
    url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={cid}&key={api_key}".format(
        cid=cid, api_key=API_KEY
    )
    d = requests.get(url).json()
    return d['items'][0]['snippet']['channelTitle']

def main():
    video_id = "..."
    channel_id = get_channel_id(video_id)
    channel_title = get_channel_title(channel_id)
    print(channel_id)
    print(channel_title)
```